# How do I find how much actual CPU a kubernetes pod/container is using?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, resource-utilization

I am trying to optimize the CPU resources allocated to a pod based on previous runs of that pod.

The only problem is that I have only been able to find how much CPU is allocated to a given pod, not how much CPU a pod is actually using.

Comment: you can try portainer https://hub.docker.com/r/portainer/portainer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That information is not stored anywhere in Kubernetes. You typically can get the 'current' CPU utilization from a metrics endpoint.

You will have to use another system/database to store that information through time. The most common one to use is the open-source time series DB [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). You can also visualize its content using another popular tool: [Grafana](https://grafana.com/).  There are other open-source alternatives too. For example, [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/).

Also, there are a ton of commercial solutions that support Kubernetes metrics. For example:

- [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/)
- [Sysdig](https://sysdig.com/)
- [SignalFX](https://www.signalfx.com/)
- [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/)
- [Dynatrace](https://www.dynatrace.com/)
- Etc...

Answer (score 2):

I may be reading too much into how the question is worded: (quote) "how much CPU a pod is actually using"...even though the question also mentions (quote) "to optimize...based on previous runs". So:

For usage history - see Rico's answer.

For current usage, see [`kubectl top`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-pod-em-). Use `watch` to see usage stats every 2 seconds without having to run the command over and over. For example:

```
watch kubectl top pod <pod-name> --namespace=<namespace-name>
```

This can be helpful, too: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-usage-monitoring/#resource-metrics-pipeline

Comment: Just a note that `kubectl top` requires a metrics server or heapster which isn't always installed.

Answer (score 0):

consider github.com/dpetzold/kube-resource-explorer

```
# /opt/go/bin/kube-resource-explorer -namespace kube-system -reverse -sort MemReq
Namespace    Name                                                                                                                     CpuReq        CpuReq%  CpuLimit      CpuLimit%  MemReq           MemReq%  MemLimit         MemLimit%
---------    ----                                                                                                                     ------        -------  --------      ---------  ------           -------  --------         ---------
kube-system  calico-node-sqh7m/calico-node                                                                                            250m          3%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  metrics-server-58699455bc-kz4r9/metrics-server                                                                           0m            0%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-proxy-hftdz/kube-proxy                                                                                              100m          1%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-proxy-x72g6/kube-proxy                                                                                              100m          1%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-proxy-fhtqm/kube-proxy                                                                                              100m          1%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  tiller-deploy-5b7c66d59c-b72hk/tiller                                                                                    0m            0%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  calico-node-xvfjf/calico-node                                                                                            250m          3%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  calico-node-ptq8l/calico-node                                                                                            250m          3%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  addon-http-application-routing-external-dns-855cdc4946-jh68m/addon-http-application-routing-external-dns                 0m            0%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller-6bfljzb/addon-http-application-routing-nginx-ingress-controller  0m            0%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  calico-node-wsxp7/calico-node                                                                                            250m          3%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  calico-typha-86bcb74584-vwq5d/calico-typha                                                                               0m            0%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  calico-typha-horizontal-autoscaler-79d4669c84-7kd6s/autoscaler                                                           10m           0%       10m           0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-proxy-xq5cq/kube-proxy                                                                                              100m          1%       0m            0%         0Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-nqpf6/redirector                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         2Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-k4zrl/redirector                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         2Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-kx8l5/redirector                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         2Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-pwd5r/redirector                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         2Mi              0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  coredns-autoscaler-657d77ffbf-ld6jp/autoscaler                                                                           20m           0%       0m            0%         10Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  addon-http-application-routing-default-http-backend-74698cnzjt8/addon-http-application-routing-default-http-backend      10m           0%       10m           0%         20Mi             0%       20Mi             0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-nqpf6/azureproxy                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         32Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-k4zrl/azureproxy                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         32Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-pwd5r/azureproxy                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         32Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kube-svc-redirect-kx8l5/azureproxy                                                                                       5m            0%       0m            0%         32Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  kubernetes-dashboard-6f697bd9f5-sjtnf/main                                                                               100m          1%       100m          1%         50Mi             0%       500Mi            1%
kube-system  tunnelfront-6bb9dcf868-hh6kp/tunnel-front                                                                                10m           0%       0m            0%         64Mi             0%       0Mi              0%
kube-system  coredns-7fbf4847b6-gtnpb/coredns                                                                                         100m          1%       0m            0%         70Mi             0%       170Mi            0%
kube-system  coredns-7fbf4847b6-qcsgb/coredns                                                                                         100m          1%       0m            0%         70Mi             0%       170Mi            0%
kube-system  omsagent-rs-7b98f76d84-kj9v6/omsagent                                                                                    50m           0%       150m          1%         175Mi            0%       500Mi            1%
kube-system  omsagent-7m8vs/omsagent                                                                                                  75m           0%       150m          1%         225Mi            0%       600Mi            2%
kube-system  omsagent-8xcng/omsagent                                                                                                  75m           0%       150m          1%         225Mi            0%       600Mi            2%
kube-system  omsagent-q6dj4/omsagent                                                                                                  75m           0%       150m          1%         225Mi            0%       600Mi            2%
kube-system  omsagent-whnbp/omsagent                                                                                                  75m           0%       150m          1%         225Mi            0%       600Mi            2%
kube-system  cluster-autoscaler-7c694f79fd-rzftb/cluster-autoscaler                                                                   100m          1%       200m          2%         300Mi            1%       500Mi            1%
---------    ----                                                                                                                     ------        -------  --------      ---------  ------           -------  --------         ---------
Total                                                                                                                                 2240m/31644m  7%       1070m/31644m  3%         1795Mi/111005Mi  1%       4260Mi/111005Mi  3%
```

Answer (score -1):

From docker, you can query a container with `docker stats`. To show the instantaneous stats, including CPU, memory, and network usage, of all containers:

```
docker stats --no-stream
```

For gathering the metrics over time, cAdvisor, Prometheus, and Grafana together are a common open source metrics gathering, storage, and viewing set of tools.